# select by id in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

as all you know

```
$("#ID")
```

returns the element having ID.

but this code always return  even there's no element.

```
alert($("#htrBuyerCouponNotice"));
alert(document.getElementById("htrBuyerConponNotice"));
```

in this case.

those two line results are diffrent.

I want to check whether  there is an element  has `htrBuyerCouponNotice`.

`document.getElementByID`  return null  if there's no element.

Comment: It's not because of the typo in Coupon/Conpon, is it? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the [`length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) property of the jQuery object to determine the number of matched elements, e.g.:

```
alert($(selector).length);
```

You can use it directly on `if` statements e.g.:

```
var $el = $(selector);

if ($el.length) { // only 0 will coerce to false
  // ...
}
```

But most of the time you don't really need to know if the selector matched elements or not, because the jQuery built-in methods will be simply ignored, e.g.:

```
$('#nonExistent').hide();
```

The above statement will not cause any error even if the element was not found.

jQuery has also the `size` method, but I would recommend you to use the `length` property directly since it's publicly accessible, the `size` method is slightly slower since it is only a function that returns the value of `length` property.

Answer (score 1):

because jQuery returns a list of selected elements, if there are no elements, you still get a return - its just a empty list.

check for $('#someID').length - should work if i remember corretly

Answer (score 1):

When selecting elements, jQuery will always return an array of matching elements.  In your case, `$('#htrBuyerCouponNotice')` is probably returning an empty array.  Instead, check `$('#htrBuyerCouponNotice').length`.

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("#htrBuyerCouponNotice").size()
```

It'll be zero if there's no nodes with that identifier, 1 if there is.